# Are packages override each other?

Tags: linux, packages

I need to install `libstdc++.so.`**5**  and `libstdc++.so.`**6** packages. If I install 6 version of package (assuming I have already installed 5 version) it will override 5 version? Or these packages can exist together?

Comment: Which distro are you using ?

Comment: @Iain  I use CentOS 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two packages can exist together.